# Inserting cell in specific section

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to find a way that allows me to insert a new cell under a specific section on my tableview. There is a button that is pressed called "add song" and once a user presses on that it should insert a new cell that is built by with a prototype cell. That prototype cell will allow a user to click on it and edit certain information on that cell. I have been trying to code a way to insert the cell below the cell that is currently in that section which is section "3". I'm sure it is something simple that I am messing up since I'm not very use to doing tableviews. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class MultipleSongsTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func addSong(_ sender: Any) {
        insertNewSongCell()
    }

    func insertNewSongCell() {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: -1, section: 3)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

extension MultipleSongsTableViewController {


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 2 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 3 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 1
        }
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "trackTitleCell", for: indexPath) as! ReleaseTitleTableViewCell


                     return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "genreCell", for: indexPath) as! Genre2TableViewCell

            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrackListCell", for: indexPath) as! TrackListTableViewCell

            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 3 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TrackListSongCells", for: indexPath) as! TrackListSongsTableViewCell


            return cell
        } else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddSongButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! AddSongTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is a screenshot of how my viewcontroller looks and where I expect the new cell to populate. [image: Simulator Screen Shot]

I would like the new cell to be inserted after the cell that says "Song Name", I would like the inserted cell to be the same prototype cell that is currently there because the user can click on that cell and fill out information and change the current "Song Name" label to what ever they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need a data source array for the section for example

```
var songs = [String]()
```

Then you have to modify `numberOfRowsInSection` to return the number of songs for section 3. This method can be simplified anyway

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
        case 3: return songs.count
        default: return 1
    }
}
```

Now you can add a new song to the array and insert the row

```
func insertNewSongCell() {
    let insertionIndex = songs.count
    songs.append("New Song")
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: insertionIndex, section: 3)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

`beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` have no effect in this case, you can omit the lines.

Comment: Thank you, I see what was I doing in correctly. Thank you for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [UITableView.insertRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) will insert cells into your `UITableView`.  You can insert exactly 1 cell by passing an `indexPaths` argument containing 1 `IndexPath`:

```
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 3)], with: .automatic)
```

You may need to also update your `UITableViewDataSource` to return expected values, e.g. from its [tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview), to account for the additional row(s).  Otherwise, your app will throw an unhandled exception and crash.